# angular with bootstrap typeahead

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have been trying to make my Typeahead work:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    <input type="text" name="name{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.name" [ngbTypeahead]="searchItem" />
</div>
```

the component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    searchItem: any;

    ngOninit() {
        this.searchItem = (text$: Observable<string>) => text$.pipe(
            debounceTime(250),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            switchMap((itemName: string) => itemName.length >= 2 ? this.service.getItems() ? of([])),
            switchMap((items: Item[]) => items.length > 0 ? items.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur.name], []) : [])
        );
    }
}
```

At runtime after I type in 2 letters in the Typeahead, Angular gives me the following error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object 'xxxx' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

where 'xxxx' is the `name` property of an item.

But if I change the `reduce` function to the following:

```
switchMap((items: Item[]) => items.length > 0 ? items.reduce((acc, cur) => [[...acc, cur.name]], []) : [])
```

where it returns an array with only one element which is another array, Angular will not give me any error but will show the first 2 values in the same line in the Typeahead popup and the 3rd in the 2nd line. (The service returns 3 items.)

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to create typehead in loop?

Comment: I think your'e typing error, I think is items.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur.name], []) -not double [-

Comment: @Eliseo As I said earlier, single brackets gave me the error and double didn't give me any error but the first 2 strings were put into one line in the typeahead popup.

Comment: @PareshGami It gave me the same error if I create the typeaheads in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the current Bootstrap Typeahead doesn't work with `switchMap` but `map` as in the example in the doc.